How to implement dependent/nested workflows and actions in a shared repo?
Overview
I have a collection of reusable workflows and actions that are needed in multiple repositories. I want to store these in a single "infra" repo.
There is a single entry point, a reusable workflow, which needs to call other workflows/action from the same repository/ref as the entry point.
Github documentation states:

If you use the uses: ./path/to/local/workflow.yaml syntax the called workflow is from the same commit as the caller workflow.


https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/reusing-workflows#calling-a-reusable-workflow

However, GHA doesn't seem to be able to locate the called workflows in the shared repository, even though the caller workflow (the entry point) is also in the shared repo.
Testbed
I have a testing implementation here:

User repo: https://github.com/alliepiper/test_gha
Shared repo: https://github.com/alliepiper/test_gha_infra

Those might get deleted at some point, so I'll include an annotated implementation below:
Implementation
The workflow/action definitions are:

User workflow: alliepiper/test_gha/.github/workflows/level-0.yml
Invokes the entry point workflow from the remote repo:
name: Project Workflow
on:
  workflow_dispatch:
jobs:
  call-reusable-workflow:
    uses: alliepiper/test_gha_infra/.github/workflows/level-1.yml@v1

This works.

Shared workflow entry point: alliepiper/test_gha_infra/.github/workflows/level-1.yml
Invokes a second reusable workflow from the current test_gha_infra repository of shared GHA infra using a local path in uses.
name: First remote reusable workflow
on:
  workflow_call:
jobs:
  call-reusable-workflow:
    uses: ./.github/workflows/level-2.yml

This fails (error below). The remaining workflow/action are not reached.

Second shared workflow: alliepiper/test_gha_infra/.github/workflows/level-2.yml
Invokes an action from the current test_gha_infra repository of shared GHA infra using a local path in uses.
name: Nested Remote Reusable Workflow
on:
  workflow_call:
jobs:
  invoke-action:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Run the action
        uses: ./.github/actions/level-3


Shared action: alliepiper/test_gha_infra/.github/actions/level-3/action.yml
Just prints hello world.
name: "Nested remote reusable action"
runs:
  using: "composite"
  steps:
    - name: Output
      shell: bash
      run: |
        echo "Hello World!"

Error message
Link: https://github.com/alliepiper/test_gha/actions/runs/10079373441
Error message:
Invalid workflow file: .github/workflows/level-0.yml#L12
error parsing called workflow
".github/workflows/level-0.yml"
-> "alliepiper/test_gha_infra/.github/workflows/level-1.yml@v1" (source tag with sha:e7a9ca6ce6d0d85d16d24e9715abe852dc92bb7e)
--> "./.github/workflows/level-2.yml"
: workflow was not found. See https://docs.github.com/actions/learn-github-actions/reusing-workflows#access-to-reusable-workflows for more information.


My guess would be that in deeper levels, you are still in the context of the top-level calling repo, which doesn't have ./.github/workflows/level-2.yml. Have you tried using uses: alliepiper/test_gha_infra/.github/workflows/level-2.yml@v1 fully qualified in  level-1.yml? I understand you'd prefer not to have to qualify it each time, but that could still be a usable workaround if it works.

That does seem to be what's happening -- the called workflow isn't using the same commit as the caller workflow (as the documentation says), but rather the root workflow. Fully qualifying everything would work for the toy example, but makes it impossible (or at least, exceptionally tedious and fragile!) to manage versioning.

I've also reported this to github, since this does seem to be a bug given the documentation: https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/133424

I've forked your repo and played around with things, and indeed, when invoked from test_gha, pwd and find report that we're at the root of the test_gha sandbox, and it's only when we're invoking level 3 from within test_gha_infra that we find ourselves in the right place. I agree, doing these tests, I very clearly observed the nuisance of having the specify the exact tag for repo to get the right version of level 3, that's an extra burden and a gotcha that's really easy to forget to update.

You need to provide full path for all higher levels, such as:
uses: alliepiper/test_gha_infra/.github/workflows/level-2.yml
The relative path will only work for local files at base level when the repo is checkedout
